# What are Valid feature class and table names in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, documentation

What are the rules for naming valid feature classes and tables in ArcGIS Desktop, and is there any supporting document which can explain all the dataset naming limitations?

Comment: Depends on what datatype you are using, eh?

Comment: I am using shape file and file geodatabase

Comment: something poorly documented: don't use a number for the first character of a dataset.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, i am trying to use number for the first character of dataset, no problem in shape file but file geodatabase is giving me error

Comment: Sorry, but trying to solve a similar problem: while importing in gdb, how do I add date before the name? ex: name.shp -> 120706_name feature class

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's in the documentation:  [Defining feature class properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002200000002000000.htm)

Specifically:

> Names must begin with a letter, not a
>   number or special character such as an
>   asterisk (*) or percent sign (%).
>   Names can't have any characters other than alphanumeric characters and underscores.

Answer (score 7):

This question has been answered by Swingley above... But, in terms of automating this procedure, you could write a script that implements the **IFieldChecker.ValidateTableName** method. If i remember correctly it returns a corrected name with invalid characters replaced with underscores.

Comment: I am aware of validateTableName but here is my situation, i have shape files "1-Digit postcode.shp, 2-digit postcode.shp" and when i use validateTableName on these two shape file i will get result for both "_Digit_postcode.shp". I think i need to write my own function for this table name validation.

Comment: it's been a whole so correct me if i am wrong but if you use the workspace parameter, you should in fact get "_Digit_postcode.shp" and "_Digit_postcode_1.shp"

Answer (score 0):

Since ArcGIS 10.3, there is an `arcpy` function [`ValidateTableName`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/validatetablename.htm):

> Takes a table name and a workspace path and returns a valid table name
>   for the workspace. An underscore "_" will replace any invalid
>   character found in the table name and will honor the name restrictions
>   for the workspace. The table name restrictions depend on the specific
>   RDBMS used.