# Using "." in layers name

Tags: arcpy, layers

I have a strange bug (?) using arcpy when I try to create a layer with a point inside the name. Let's consider I write:

```
N = 26.1
outLocation = "C:/Project/ArcGIS/MyLayers/"    
outputName =  "SimpleName_"+str(N)
geometry_type = "POINT"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outLocation, outputName, geometry_type)
```

The layer is created but it gets the name **SimpleName_24** instead of **SimpleName_24.1**

Is it something that can be corrected?
I also tried `"SimpleName_"+str(N)[:2]+"."+str(N)[3:]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you creating a shapefile or a feature in a geodatabase?

Comment: You should really avoid anything but a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and `_` in names and paths, especially in combination with Python. Will save you a lot of headaches...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using "." in feature class name is not supported (invalid).  You cannot create a fc with a "." character.  Maybe use "_" underscore character instead.  Here is a q/a defining naming rules:

[What are Valid feature class and table names in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/what-are-valid-feature-class-and-table-names-in-arcgis-desktop)